# Is it nessary to call servicehost.close method before the host application ends

Tags: wcf

I am wondering if it is necessary to call servicehost.close before the application ends?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the close and I avoid a using block after reading this article

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/26/dont-wrap-wcf-service-hosts-or-clients-in-a-using-statement/